# How to respond to an unknown candidate asking for a referral?

Tags: linkedin, referral

I'm part of a graduate program at a large multinational company (I joined about a year ago) and I had recently shared on LinkedIn about an opening for the same program for this year, stating that I am happy to answer any questions about the program. A recently graduated student who I do not know has contacted me asking if there is a way for him to 'apply through HR' as his resume was rejected when he applied for the program. I'm not sure what to reply as there is a way to 'apply through HR' which is by referral but I'm not comfortable referring someone who I personally have not worked with or observed, otherwise there would be no merit for any of my referrals. Also, he has not explicitly asked for a referral from me either.

What would be the most appropriate way to respond to him? I know the job market is really tough for recent graduates so I definitely do want to help him out (maybe by offering a resume review).

**Edit** My question was how to politely let him know I will not be giving a referral and still offer to help him out by suggesting what skills he could improve etc, not should I give him a referral or not if that wasn't clear.

Comment: *"...as his resume was rejected when he applied for the program."* - If this person was already rejected, I think referring them and repeating the process will end in the same result... don't you think? You already stated you are not comfortable with referring them and was not explicitly asked for that neither... so... looking for a polite way to say no perhaps? Or are you actually willing to refer them (if not then it's clear you have to politely say no or say there is no other way if they were already rejected)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Do not make a "referral" for someone you do not know.** You have already stated the reasons for this.

For a company the whole point of getting referrals is that somebody at the company vouches for them to some extent - that they are at least honest and reasonable people and not grossly incompetent. To make a referral for someone you don't know defeats that.

Your credibility is on the line here. If they turn out to be a fraud, or utterly incompetent, or a toxic person, you will suffer if you have referred them.

Reviewing their resume is no real help. HR have already reviewed it and determined that it doesn't meet the company requirements. If you can add no information to that then they are unlikely to change their minds.

Respond to this person by saying that you don't make referrals for people you don't know, and that if they were rejected by HR then they would probably be rejected anyway.

The only exception would be if you know someone who knows this person.

Answer (score -2):

First, clarify that he truly wants a referral. If so...

Ask for his resume. Review it by yourself with an open mind. It's possible he really is qualified and the system missed him. Then, give him honest, brief feedback. If you do not want to refer him, don't, and give the reason you gave us. You can tell him you'll let him know if you come across a role that's a good fit.

Alternatively, after you review his resume, you can tell him, "I'll do what I can, but don't get your hopes up. This is very competitive."